# How to generate example SOAP request with SoapUI in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I would like to write some code in Java, which will be generate examples SOAP request for given WSDL files. 
The code below do it for every opperation of web services, but instead of example data in SOAP request. I have question mark. I don't need execute request, but only write this request.
I know that it is possible(like in SoapUi) but I don't know how I can do it.

I'll be grateful for Yours help.

Best regards.
Lukasz

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "sample.wsdl");
        WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];

        for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
            WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
            WsdlRequest request = op.addNewRequest("My Request");
            System.out.println("#" + op.getName() + "#\n" + op.createRequest(true));
        }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
public String getRequestResult(String wsdl, String operationName)
        throws Exception {
    // create new project
    WsdlProjectPro project = new WsdlProjectPro();

    // import amazon wsdl
    WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, wsdl,
            true)[0];

    // get desired operation
    WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) iface
            .getOperationByName(operationName);

    // create a new empty request for that operation
    WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest("Java Req");

    // generate the request content from the schema
    request.setRequestContent(operation.createRequest(true));

    // submit the request
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    WsdlSubmit submit = (WsdlSubmit) request.submit(new WsdlSubmitContext(
            request), false);

    // wait for the response
    Response response = submit.getResponse();

    return response.getContentAsString();
}
```